# 1366x768 not working in windows 11

Tags: windows, drivers

Ok I updated to windows 11. I booted monitor shows that it's in 1240x720 85hz and says to change it to 1366x768 60hz(stock) it has happened in windows 10 and I fixed it by disabling my graphics driver from safe mode and using custom resolution utility in windows 10 to change the refresh rate and resolution because monitor just doesn't works if the refresh rate is above 61 hz but now nothing works. I tried reinstalling drivers also clean installing windows 11 but custom resolution utility just doesn't works.

Comment: In a video about windows 11 from Linus Tech Tips, they mentioned that it was still being developed and as such they only could use a weird 1600x1200 resolution, as like in a VM. So its possible you got an early version that doesn't work well with other resolutions yet.

Comment: It is likely your particular display and monitor. My Windows 11 Insider machine has a native 1366x768 monitor and it displays fine. Use the Feedback Hub to notify Microsoft.

Comment: I guess it's the vga cable is the problem because the cable which came with the monitor is not working and when it was working it had no issues with resolution and other stuff it was just plug and play but when I bought a new one it just doesn't like my drivers and I hardly managed my 10 year old 60 hz monitor tk run at 85 hz and tried to make a custom resolution in my driver settings and it says it's not compatible but CRU works so I don't know if it's the driver or the cable I'm done with this thing